# why can tcpListener.Start create a process but crashes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tcp, tcplistener, tcpserver

I am trying to create a TCP server.

I checked with the command `netsh firewall show state` (command line) and found an open TCP port (XXXX).
Then I checked using the tool TCPView (equivalent to "netstat" command) that this port was not in use.
Then I run in C# the following code:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, XXXX);
tcpListener.Start();
```

When I press "Start" button in VS, a new process appeared in the TCPView tool with the Local Port defined in C#.
However, after this VS stops and throws the following error:

"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'"

This problem seems to be new from already asked questions because in this case the `tcpListener.Start()` created successfully a process in the specified  port.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like your code is calling the same thing twice

Comment: The error is self explanatory, make sure you aren't calling this twice, or you don't have an application open that is using it.

Comment: Yes I was calling it twice! Thanks!